# ionic platform.ready() is not working in @ionic/angular 6.0.4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

My ionic info is

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 3 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/opt/android)
   NodeJS            : v14.16.1 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.12
   OS                : Linux 5.10
```

The development environment uses a docker container. The image uses https://hub.docker.com/r/beevelop/ionic.

In the code below, platform.ready () does not work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      alert("test");
    });
  }

}
```

For the operation verification, we used the actual android machine. I installed and confirmed the built apk file with`adb install app-debug.apk`.
What may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your cordova platform to 10.1.1. after that will work
your Cordova Platforms is : android 9.1.0

cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@10.1.1

Comment: Thank you. After installing cordova-android10, it worked fine!